# correlated variables as fixed effect in mixed effect models

Tags: mixed-model

I am interested to know whether the count of beetles depends more on precipitation or in minimum temperature in winter.  I currently model as fixed effects:

- altitude (correlated with temperature)
- minimum temperature,
- temperature (which is correlated with minimum temperature)
- precipitation

and as random effects

- year (data has been collected over 20 years)
- region
- technician (who did the measurements)

My question is: If the variables treated as fixed effects are correlated, is it better to add them all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you write out the models you're asking about so we can see which variables you are thinking of as correlated with which other ones.  e.g. do you mean independent variables correlated with each other, or independent variables correlated with unobserved confounders captured by the fixed effect parameters, or represented in the random effect distribution, or something else.

Comment: I am interested to know whether the count of beetles depends more on precipitation or in minimum temperature in winter. I have as explanatory variables: altitude (correlated with temperature), minimum temperature, precipitation, temperature (which is correlated with minimum temperature); which I add as fixed effect. further predictor variables are year (data has been collected over 20 years), region, and technician (who did the measurements), which I add as random effects.question: for the fixed effect, if variables are correlated, is it better to add them all?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewriting your question to reflect the very illuminating comment above.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first cut at the question.

Fixed effects correlated between themselves are not necessarily problematic. Correlation may make it harder to assign variance to different variables, that's actually just reflecting the smaller amount of information in the data.

Fixed effects correlated with random effects are potentially more problematic.  This seems to be your situation.  Specifically I would guess that all the fixed effects are correlated with region.  The Hausmann test tries to see whether this will matter to inferences about your fixed effects, but it seems it's not particularly powerful.  In any case, a traditional way around the problem, due to Mundlak, involves putting group-averaged fixed effect levels as covariates to predict the random effects.  A clear discussion of these issues - not ecology I'm afraid - can be found in

Bell, A. J. D. and Jones, K. 2015, [Explaining Fixed Effects: Random Effects modelling of Time-Series Cross-Sectional and Panel Data](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S2049847014000077). Political Science Research and Methods, vol 3., pp. 133-153 ([preprint](http://psych.colorado.edu/~westfaja/FixedvsRandom.pdf))

This also emphasises the upsides of the slightly more elaborate modeling this requires.

So, to answer your question: Should you put them all in?  If you want.  The question is more, where and how should you put them in if you do.

Comment: Dear conjugateprior - Yoy say *Fixed effects correlated between themselves are not necessarily problematic* - I am having exactly the same question as OP (several dependent factors in a linear mixed model) , so this answer is of great interest to me, but would you have any literature on this that supports your claim? +1